# Writing a loop for multiple boolean conditions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, boolean

I have a dataset which contains events and the corresponding time (epoch number) when they occur.  I would like to reformat this data to record whether each event type occurs at a certain epoch section in binary format.

```
##Current Dataframe:
df<- data.frame(Epoch = c (99,126,136,148,150,200,228,247,268,269,285,285,294,308,309,319,320,324,326,337,338,352,353,380,382,418,419,424,431,437,440,447,449,470,515,548,550,550,561,589,590,596,598,603,612,616,623,626,633,655,663,668,682,687,704,708,717,730,744,752,771,794,810,811,816,819,825,832,832,841,847,851,853,868,871,881,893,915,918,922,935,943),
                Event = c( "hypopnea","auto_trig","double_trig","auto_trig","double_trig"   , "double_trig" ,"hypopnea" ,"hypopnea","auto_trig" ,"double_trig","auto_trig","double_trig"  , "double_trig" ,"auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "double_trig" , "double_trig", "hypopnea","hypopnea" ,"double_trig","double_trig","hypopnea", "double_trig" ,"hypopnea" , "double_trig", "high_leak", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig" ,"double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "auto_trig",  "double_trig", "hypopnea",  "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig","double_trig","auto_trig", "auto_trig","hypopnea",    "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "hypopnea" , "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "ineffective_eff", "ineffective_eff", "double_trig", "double_trig", "high_leak", "double_trig",  "hypopnea", "auto_trig", "hypopnea","double_trig", "high_leak", "double_trig", "high_leak", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig",   "double_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig"))
```

I would like to put these corresponding events into a new data frame:

```
df2<- data.frame(Section = seq(1, max(df$Epoch/10+1), by = 1),
                Epoch5 = seq(1, max(df$Epoch), by =10),
                Epoch51 =seq(11, max(df$Epoch)+10, by = 10))
```

So that when df$Epoch is >=Epoch5 AND <Epoch51 AND df$Event == "hypopnea" , a new column hypopnea = 1 (and repeated for all events).

I have tried writing if/else loops and dplyr::case_when but because I need to expand the original data frame to binary long format I keep coming up with missing data issues.

Any suggestions about how best to transpose this data is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi AR459! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: What's the meaning of 5 and 51 in Epoch5 and Epoch51?

Comment: Thanks Mark- it was just a way for me to remember the different intervals at which I needed the events to be recorded in

Answer (score 0):

In base R this can be done by splitting `Epoch` by `Event`, then `sapply` to each vector a function finding where in the intervals `Epoch5` to `Epoch51` its elements are. A fast function able to do this is `findInterval`.

```r
sp <- split(df$Epoch, df$Event)
sp
#> $auto_trig
#>  [1] 126 148 268 285 308 319 324 437 447 550 590 598 616 623 668 687 825 853 915
#> 
#> $double_trig
#>  [1] 136 150 200 269 285 294 309 320 326 337 353 380 418 424 440 449 470 515 550
#> [20] 589 596 603 612 633 655 663 682 708 717 730 744 794 810 816 832 847 868 871
#> [39] 881 893 918 922 935 943
#> 
#> $high_leak
#> [1] 431 811 841 851
#> 
#> $hypopnea
#>  [1]  99 228 247 338 352 382 419 548 561 626 704 819 832
#> 
#> $ineffective_eff
#> [1] 752 771

nms <- names(sp)
E <- c(df2$Epoch5, max(df2$Epoch51))

tmp_test <- sapply(nms, \(i) {
  sec <- findInterval(sp[[i]], E)
  df2$Section %in% sec |> as.integer()
})

head(tmp_test)
#>      auto_trig double_trig high_leak hypopnea ineffective_eff
#> [1,]         0           0         0        0               0
#> [2,]         0           0         0        0               0
#> [3,]         0           0         0        0               0
#> [4,]         0           0         0        0               0
#> [5,]         0           0         0        0               0
#> [6,]         0           0         0        0               0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Now the complete code. I will use R's new pipe operator, introduced in R 4.1.

```r
sp <- split(df$Epoch, df$Event)
nms <- names(sp)
E <- c(df2$Epoch5, max(df2$Epoch51))

df2 <- df2 |>
  cbind(
    sapply(nms, \(i) {
      sec <- findInterval(sp[[i]], E)
      df2$Section %in% sec |> as.integer()
    })
  )

rm(sp, nms, E)  # tidy up
head(df2)
#>   Section Epoch5 Epoch51 auto_trig double_trig high_leak hypopnea ineffective_eff
#> 1       1      1      11         0           0         0        0               0
#> 2       2     11      21         0           0         0        0               0
#> 3       3     21      31         0           0         0        0               0
#> 4       4     31      41         0           0         0        0               0
#> 5       5     41      51         0           0         0        0               0
#> 6       6     51      61         0           0         0        0               0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The following function generalizes the code above. Its two main arguments are `data`and `data2`, corresponding to `df` and `df2`, respectively.

Two groups of tests are run,

1. with one list of data.frames, `list(df, df, etc)`;
2. with two lists of data.frames, the second being `list(df2, df2, etc)`.

Both groups of tests test base R and `purrr` code.
In the two lists case the lists must have the same length, to each `df` corresponds one `df2`.

```r
encode_events <- function(data, data2, epoch = "Epoch", event = "Event", section = "Section",
                          epoch5 = "Epoch5", epoch51 = "Epoch51") {
  sp <- split(data[[epoch]], data[[event]])
  nms <- names(sp)
  E <- c(data2[[epoch5]], max(data2[[epoch51]]))
  
  data2 |>
    cbind(
      sapply(nms, \(i) {
        sec <- findInterval(sp[[i]], E)
        data2[[section]] %in% sec |> as.integer()
      })
    )
}

df_list <- list(df, df)

# 1st group of tests
# with one list of data.frames, list(df, df)
result_list_1a <- purrr::map(df_list, \(x, y) encode_events(x, y), y = df2)
result_list_1b <- mapply(encode_events, df_list, MoreArgs = list(data2 = df2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

identical(result_list_1a, result_list_1b)
#> [1] TRUE

# 2nd group of tests
# with two list of data.frames, list(df, df) and list(df2, df2)
df2_list <- list(df2, df2)
result_list_2a <- purrr::map2(df_list, df2_list, encode_events)
result_list_2b <- Map(encode_events, df_list, df2_list)
result_list_2c <- mapply(encode_events, df_list, df2_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

identical(result_list_2a, result_list_2b)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(result_list_2a, result_list_2c)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Rui- is it possible to generalise this code to a large list of data frames using the purrr::map function? If so, how would you do this?

Comment: @AR459 Yes, it is possible to generalize this code, do all the df's have columns named `"Epoch"` and `"Event"`?

Comment: Hi Rui- yes they do: they're actually called "Epoch" and "Events"